# Merge ARFF files together by common attribute

Tags: java, merge, weka, data-processing, arff

I currently have two separate ARFF files for use in a Java program i'm writing that uses WEKAs machine learning algorithms. The two files are in the format:

```
@attribute movieID numeric
@attribute title {whole, host, of, movie, titles}
@attribute genres {whole, list, of, genres}
```

and

```
@attribute movieID numeric
@attribute tags {very, long, list, of, possible, tags}
@attribute timestamp numeric
```

In an ideal world i am looking to 'join' these two files by their movieID's so the relevant tags would be assigned to the movies however i am not sure if this is possible? Having had a fair old search i'm not sure exactly how to go about this or in general to create a single dataset for use with the rest of the program with studies association rules. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This isn't a very sophisticated solution but, I would convert the two ARFF files to .csv within Weka.  Then using Excel or something similar, I would open each file and sort the movieID's, then simply combine the two files by copying the different columns.  After that, I would use Weka to read in the csv and resave as a .arff.

Answer (score 0):

*foreign* package in R is capable of reading and writing ARFF files.

- You can first read both files in two different data frames in R (see
  [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/read.arff.html)).
- Then use the "merge" command to join the data frames in any way you need (see
  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)).
- Finally, you can easily write the new data frame in a new ARFF file (see
  [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/write.arff.html)).